# How to sort the list by descending order

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Items {
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public List<string> SubItems {get; set;}
}
```

Above is my class.
And somewhere in my code I am using List and adding the records.

```
List<Items> listOfItems = new List<Items>();
listOfItems.OrderByDescending(i => i.SubItems).ToList();
```

listOfItems has some data.
I want to order the **SubItems** which are in **listOfItems** list through LINQ query.

Comment: Have you tried `.OrderBy()` when selecting your results?

Comment: tried. not working for me

Comment: @Sherlock How is it not working? Also, how do you expect `SubItems` to be ordered? By its `Id`? By its `Name`? By its position in memory? You're missing half the question.

Comment: SubItems is a List<string> but it has values like versions like below 

1.0, 1.2, 1.5, 1.9, 2.0. @KieranDevlin

Comment: Then you should add what you've tried and why it is not working for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with LINQ, as LINQ is **query**, and you want to **change** your data in place, not to query something from the data. But you still can use ordinal loop for sorting the content for each `Item`

```
listOfItems.ForEach(x=>x.SubItems.Sort((a, b) => b.CompareTo(a)))
```

or

```
listOfItems.ForEach(x=>x.SubItems = x.SubItems.OrderByDescending(i => i)))
```

Comment: Could you help me with this?

 listOfItems.ForEach(x => x. SubItems.AddRange(serviceVersions));
                            listOfItems.ForEach(x => x. SubItems.Sort((a, b) => b.CompareTo(a)));

How to combine both the foreach loop and make single query and yet get sorted

@Serg

Comment: Just join both `AddRange` and `Sort` in single lambda. `listOfItems.ForEach(x => {x. SubItems.AddRange(serviceVersions); x. SubItems.Sort((a, b) => b.CompareTo(a));});`. Or just replace `ForEach` method with ordinal `foreach` loop. This may improve readability.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that the OrderBy() returns new list, which you are currently not storing anywhere. So it should be:

```
List<Items> listOfItems = new List<Items>();

var orderedList = listOfItems.OrderByDescending(i => i.SubItems).ToList();
```